# Alexa Node js Lambda Function is giving response null

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm returning a response from Nodejs Lambda function and is giving a blank response like this :

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Welcome to Alexa Skill"
    },
    "shouldEndSession": true
  },
  "response": {}
}
```

The session attribute should be blank and response should contain the content of the session attribute but it is happening exactly reverse. Here is the code to generate the response.

```
 context.succeed(
              buildResponse(
                buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to Alexa Skill", true),
                {}
              )
            )
```

and these are the helper functions:

```
function buildSpeechletResponse(outputText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: outputText
        },
        // card: {
        //     type: "Simple",
        //     title: title,
        //     content: output
        // },
        // reprompt: {
        //     outputSpeech: {
        //         type: "PlainText",
        //         text: repromptText
        //     }
        // },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}

function buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
    return {
        version: "1.0",
        sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
        response: speechletResponse
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just watch the argument order in buildResponse helper method. You are passing it in reverse. Just change as follows.

```
context.succeed(
          buildResponse({},
            buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to Alexa Skill", true)
          )
        )
```

Comment: Also, can you tell me how to get the value of the field toggle of firebase database , if the code to update its value is this :                                                       firebase.database().ref('rooms/' +loginObject.uid+'/roomdetails/01/1/appliance/0/').update({
                 toggle:1
               });